# How Do I Change My Messages On My Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id

So basically when I first set up my computer I set it up with a different apple id account now I have changed it but I still get messages from my old apple id account and can't send any to my newer contacts.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Open *System Preferences*, click on *Internet Accounts*, remove your old account and add your new account.

You could also keep your old account and add your new account along with it.